# Should the [column] tag be squashed?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, burninate-request

The [column](/questions/tagged/column) tag seems to add very little value to questions, and its meaning is ambiguous (could it refer to a database column, or a column in a table layout?).

This tag should probably be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agreed, it is now burninated.

[image: tag burninated]

Comment: [Are you sure](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/column/info)?

Comment: Ok, I burninated it again. I got "multiple" while I was in there too.

Comment: This has been causing a bunch of problems with tagging. I don't know if reburninating it has undone the steps Marc was taking to fix it. See [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157922/adding-new-tag-reflecting-to-the-wrong-tag/157923).

Comment: seems fine to me now. Column and Columns are awful, terrible tags. Neither exists on the ask question form any more.

Answer (score 6):

Effectively, the tag is used for completely different things, such as:

- Database column: [SQL - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858228/sql-column-count-doesnt-match-value-count-at-row-1)
- HTML browser attributes ("-webkit-column-width"): [Why doesn't UIWebView reflow text after column width and gap are set via javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10852435/why-doesnt-uiwebview-reflow-text-after-column-width-and-gap-are-set-via-javascr)
- Sharepoint column: [How to create an "Add Attachement" column in sharepoint 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10837830/how-to-create-an-add-attachement-column-in-sharepoint-2010)
- Grid column: [Add a button in a new column to all rows in a DataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769316/add-a-button-in-a-new-column-to-all-rows-in-a-datagrid)
- Array column (which uses also [row](/questions/tagged/row)): [PHP Grid type Array get row or column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10759420/php-grid-type-array-get-row-or-column)

I don't think the tag adds anything to the question, but the fact it is used in to mean completely different things make it useless. The question is then: Is there any expert in column that follow that tag to answer all the column-related questions? (Yes, there are 6 followers, but are they experts in columns?)

Answer (score 2):

Makes sense to me. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/811464/ssrs-sum-of-row-group-for-corresponding-column). It has 5 utterly useless tags (useless in that combination):

[column](/questions/tagged/column) [sum](/questions/tagged/sum) [row](/questions/tagged/row) [group](/questions/tagged/group) [percent](/questions/tagged/percent)

Not even one describes the technology being used.