# It's time to blacklist [server]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, tag-block-request

The [server](/questions/tagged/server) tag was burninated by Jeff Atwood during the [Great Tag Cleanup of 2012](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/128315/135887).

Since then, it's been recreated nearly every other day by people with enough reputation, but not enough tagging skill. Once created, it'll be used by the clueless a dozen times a day, literally.

It's a horrible tag teetering on the edge of being a meta tag: It *can't* stand alone, and it can mean something different to different people.

**I've been nuking it almost every day for the past three months, and it's getting old**. It's time for the blacklist.

Comment: Wait, so what you are saying is that Jeff Atwood is actually Trogdor? Mind = Blown!

Comment: Should [tag:client] also be burninated? I assume this has the same reasoning

Comment: Why are you burning the client? They are innocent. Wait... tag? Burn it.

Comment: How about blacklisting these, too: [tag:column], [tag:sum], [tag:row]  [tag:group], [tag:percent], taken from here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134267/should-the-column-tag-be-squashed/134280#134280

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII burnination by Jeff (or another mod) is actually a pretty common concept around these parts. Here's [one example](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116280/131713) of many.

Comment: @nhahtdh, no client is _ever_ innocent...

Comment: `if-statment` is one I see all the time, as well.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards - [damn it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15936194/connecting-to-ftp-from-ms-windows-server-2012-getting-530-error)

Comment: @Blah: Zero questions tagged [tag:server].  `[status-meh]`

Comment: 12 minutes ago, another one. Just got rid of it.

Comment: @Robert 2 more now. I am on mobile so it's too cumbersome to remove but I'm just saying - this needs to go forever

Comment: Meh, I've given up with the blacklist happening.  It's on my ever-growing list of 30+ tags I check regularly to ensure that they remain dead, including such gems as `conversion`, `computer`, `multiple`, `visual`, `studio`, etc...

Comment: Are you on holiday :-(... it's winning at the moment; I can't keep it clean for an entire 24 hour period without someone using it when I'm asleep or something.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards I only check two or three times day.  It's managed to be *recreated* a few days in a row this past week, judging from the number of times I've had to put back in the "DO NOT USE THIS TAG" wiki.  My list of 30 in April is now up to 59...

Answer (score 7):

> It's a horrible tag teetering on the edge of being a meta tag. It can't stand alone, and it can mean something different to different people.

Ok, I don't get the meta-tag bit. Are there waiters/waitresses posting questions and using this tag?

The "different meanings" thing is clear enough though. So... What *should* it mean? Is there one meaning among many that makes sense on SO?

Comment: Maybe because it is too broad that it doesn't make the tag any more useful than a meta-tag?

Comment: Hmm... Yeah, maybe if folks are using it in the sense of, "my code runs on a server - better throw that tag in!" Of course, that's also the dirty little secret of, say, most [tag:c#] questions.

Comment: I've counted at least three distinct meanings, all of them bad: 1) Combined with `client` when they meant to tag it `client-server`, 2) "it runs on a server" / "I'm connecting to a MySQL server", and 3) "I'm writing a server".  Oh, and `sql`+`server`, which != `sql-server`.  In any case, it's basically bait for people that have no tagging skill.  The last one *might* have some possible validity, but ... eh.

Comment: It's a generic tag.  "Hey, my code's on the server, let's add the [server] tag".  It doesn't enhance the question at all.  If it sticks around, does that mean we can have [laptop] and [pc] tags as well?  **Aw, crap they already exist!**  Burn them too!

Comment: Server can mean, in rough decreasing order of technical-ness, 1) the server end of a client/server relationship, 2) a listener on an e.g. TCP port, 3) a machine in a room that a server admin makes sure is secure and doesn't catch on fire and stuff, 4) a machine in the cloud, 5) a long-running program that responds to requests.  Note in particular load-balanced architectures de-couple (5) and (2).

Comment: Okay.  I admit it.  Meta has me confused.  There's an extended statement as a question, that has a couple of questions as an answer.