# Should the tag "lib" be removed?

Tags: support, tags, ambiguous-tags

I found the tag [lib](/questions/tagged/lib), which has no wiki / tag summary, and seems to be a synonym of the removed tag [library](/questions/tagged/library).

I guess it should be removed too.

Comment: I think it is fine as it is. just a feeling... The tag 'library' do not yet exist, I myself don't feel we need it. But very good of you to bring this up, keep up the good work.

Comment: [You'd better pray that Jeff doesn't see your question...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/138384/137537) (or maybe he should, so he can burninate this one as well)

Comment: I reckon it should stay as 'lib' but get a summary of what it is. I know in Linux, 'lib' is a library though.

Comment: @BoltClock is the edit better?

Comment: @Kevdog777: Huh? lib is short for library...

Comment: @UristMcBobby I know, that is what I said at the end: "I know in Linux, 'lib' is a library though." But what I am saying, is that if there is a lib, then it should have the definition underneath, if not, then it should be added.

Comment: @Kevdog777: Looking at the questions, you'll have a hard time figuring something out besides the "short for library" usage...and Jeff speared the head of [tag:library] and placed it in front of the main gate for all the other meta-tags to see...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Agreed, it is now burninated.

[image: tag burninated]

Comment: This picture needs more Comic Sans **Bold**.

Comment: And a "With fire."

Comment: When you say "burninated," you don't really mean blacklisted, do you?  Because you'd be using some sort of pirate symbol instead.  Also [some burninated tags seem to return](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139869/102937).  We need Trogdor with Kryptonite fire breath.