# Tag creation with a period in name

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms, tag-creation

I noticed that the tag [angular.js](/questions/tagged/angular.js) was created recently. Since [angular](/questions/tagged/angular) and [angularjs](/questions/tagged/angularjs) already exist, I decided against the creation of another synonym tag.

Shouldn't the user while creating tags be suggested that another tag with a minor difference(in this case, that of a period [`.`]) is already existent?

Comment: Or, we just remove support for periods in tag names (like we currently do for '&'). Sounds like the optimal solution.

Comment: See also / soft dupe of [Add periods (“.”) to the list of things that the tag picker ignores](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157765/135887), during which no concrete justification for ignoring periods could be found.  It still happens once or twice a day, but randomly throughout the tags instead of one tag being a chronic problem...

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Periods do occasionally come in handy for version tags, though.

Comment: @AnnaLear changed your name back, I see. But the other possibility is only allow the `.` in tags when a mod creates them, which is currently the status with version specific tags as it is.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII (re: name, yeah, I forgot it was gonna update in our internal chat rooms and the amusement value just wasn't worth it for the confusion)

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII I think version tags are only treated specially if there already is a tag that ends in a number and someone tries to create one with a different number? I don't quite recall. Either way, I like the suggestion put forth here, and other than that I don't think this needs to be an additional mod-only restriction.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII. I suspect our friends on http://mathoverflow.net might get quite upset if we took full stops out of tag names. They use arXiv classification.