# Synonym proposal: py.test and pytest

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, synonym-request

Because I don't have the required 2500 reputation on I try it this way.

I think the tag [py.test](/questions/tagged/py.test) and [pytest](/questions/tagged/pytest) are synonyms. Both tags could point only to the Python [Pytest package](http://pytest.org/) and could not be used different in my opinion.

Comment: See also: [Add periods (“.”) to the list of things that the tag picker ignores](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157765/135887)

Answer (score 2):

Merged and synonym created. Enjoy.