# Show x0 or x1 for tags with only 0 or 1 question

Tags: feature-request, tags, tags-page

On the [New Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=new) page, the number of questions using the tag is shown for each tag, except those which are used on 0 or 1 questions.

This makes it impossible to tell which bad new tags have already been removed from their questions without duplicating someone else's effort of clicking on the tag and observing that it's unused.

I'd like to see the question count for either the 0s or 1s (or possibly both) to save time when looking through new tags.

Comment: If it helps any, any tags marked created "yesterday" or older are guaranteed to have at least one question.  But yes, otherwise I wish I had more than one upvote to give...

Comment: @Charles: not if the tag was created yesterday and then removed from the question today...

Comment: @ben, what do you mean "at his work *again*"?  I never stop.  **Never**.

Comment: [LIES @Charles!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139869/its-time-to-blacklist-server#comment586789_139869) I have proof. Authenticated by your good self no less :-).

Comment: Voting to close this as a duplicate as the request here is implemented, as is answered by SE staff on the proposed dupe.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are actually 3 possible reasons for there being no number:

1. There are 0 questions tagged with this tag
2. There is 1 question tagged with this tag
3. The tag is a synonym.

This is confusing and sometimes annoying.

I would suggest that it be changed to remove those tags that have 0 questions, and which are not synonyms, and place a number by the tags that have one? Like this (poor) mock-up:

> [image: crocodiles like bamboo]

This leaves a clear delineation between tags with questions, tags without questions and synonyms (mainly because the tags without questions no longer exist!).

I'm guessing that the ones with 0 questions attached might still be around because they haven't been "deleted" yet. If it's difficult/unwanted to remove these there could be a `x 1` by the tags that do have questions and either a `x 0` by tags with no questions or a method of identifying synonyms so people can differentiate between the three possibilities.