# What is the purpose of the unknown tag?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tag-wiki

The tag [unknown](/questions/tagged/unknown) was created eight hours ago. I wanted to fill its description, but I am unsure of its purpose.

My question is: How should this tag be used?

Comment: `How should this tag be used?`  If you knew, it wouldn't be "unknown", now would it?

Comment: The sarcasm is strong with this one @Servy, +2 internetz

Comment: Also check out the `c+++` tag.  The extra `+` means **it's that good**.

Comment: On that note @blah [tag:server] got created _again_ today. [Upvote the blacklist request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139869/its-time-to-blacklist-server)!

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards - [I noticed :)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15935649/django-error-errno-32-broken-pipe)

Comment: 7 minutes ago @blah? That means it's been created (at least) _twice_ today. You just got the latest incarnation :-)

Comment: Looks like it was me who removed unknown, and then Charles.. http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15925163/revisions

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The tag has no questions; it has no purpose and has been removed. Please do not create a description/wiki.

It will be deleted within 24 hours; problem solved :-).

Comment: Well, I guess that answers my question. Thanks.

Comment: No problem @jean. Always click through and if a tag does not make sense you could consider whether it's required at all. I think in this case it might even have been me who removed it.

Comment: Isn't that [tag:untagged] @Oded? (5 questions if someone know something of the subject matter)

Comment: Is there a way to flag crappy tags? – just asking

Comment: You have over 2k rep @Jean. Use it and edit the question into shape. If you don't [Charles](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/135887/charles) is great at removing crap new tags; I just fill in when he's on holiday :-).

Comment: @Jean Not really.  You could flag a random question with the tag.  In most cases you can clean it up yourself.  If you are unsure if it should be cleaned up, or it's too much work to do yourself, post a question about it on meta as a call to action for others to discuss/address.  Mods rarely need to be involved.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards - You are right. Was thinking untagged == unknown ;)

Comment: @Oded you needed a strict comparison in javascript that could well return true. use untagged === unknown. Then for sure it will return false.

Comment: @ryan - Another JS gotcha, eh? Automatic semi-colon insertion and `parseInt` are other favorites ;)