# Can moderators to blacklist tags PERMANENTLY?

Tags: feature-request, tags, moderators

I have been reading tag complaints like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139869/its-time-to-blacklist-server). In that post, the poster seems to be *quite* annoyed at how the tag keeps coming back.

So, here's my question: **Can mods keep tags from EVER coming back?**. As in ever.

If they can't, then this would be a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) to allow mods to keep tags from coming back.

Comment: Yes, tags can be blacklisted. But this is not accessible to the moderators, only developers.

Comment: Because, heaven forbid, someone gets annoyed.  Anyway, [this idea is better](http://www.quickmeme.com/meme/3tu2qo/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moderators can't, but the community team can.

If you have a tag that you think should be blacklisted, post a question making the request - backed up with reasons why and we'll prompt the team into action.

However, it would have to be a very bad tag indeed to be blacklisted.

Comment: @ErwaySoftware: Don't bother asking for a blacklist on the [server] tag.  There's a whole bucketful of tags just like that one.  Blacklisting is reserved only for the most egregious cases.

Comment: @RobertHarvey That's why it might be a good idea to let mods do it. How is the egregiousness of a tag measured?

Comment: @ErwaySoftware: Killing kittens.

Comment: @RobertHarvey True.

Comment: @RobertHarvey How about dogs?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dog