# Adding new tag reflecting to the wrong tag

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, edits

A few minutes ago I edited "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13761034/insert-bulk-skipped-the-first-column" on Stack Overflow. But when I tried to add the [column](/questions/tagged/column) tag to the question, I got this error message:

> Creating the new tag [columns] is not allowed since the tag [column] already exists. If you think this new tag should be allowed, raise it on meta.

But I tried to add the [column](/questions/tagged/column) tag, not a [columns](/questions/tagged/columns) tag. See this screenshot of when I wrote the tag:

> [image: When I wrote the tag]

And after I clicked the <kbd>Save Edits</kbd> button:

> [image: After click Save Edit button]

Am I missing something?

Comment: *Why* do you want to create the tag `columns`? How is it different from the `column` tag? Stack Overflow is trying to prevent dupe tags from being created that only differ in wether or not they are the plural form.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Read my questions carefuly. I **don't want to add** `columns` tag. I want to add `column` tag but it gives me an error like I try to add `columns` tag.

Comment: @SonerGönül: ahAH! *pling*. Light went on, sorry.

Comment: Can we agree that `[column]` is the next candidate for a little massage from Trogdor?

Comment: Not only adding `column` tag gives this error but also editing question which is already tagged with `column` gives the same error. E.g. try to edit [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13683351/1369235)

Comment: @SulfurizedDemonbobby http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142256/166025

Answer (score 7, accepted):

casperOne [recently merged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/137367/200500) [column](/questions/tagged/column) into [columns](/questions/tagged/columns). Unfortunately, the [columns](/questions/tagged/columns) tag [no longer seems to exist](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/columns/info).

To add to the confusion, the [column](/questions/tagged/column) tag was [burninated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142256/200500) <strike>*before*</strike> after it was merged.

EDIT: I didn't look at the timestamps carefully enough. Here is a timeline of what happened:

1. Proposal for burnination of [column] - [Jun 2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134267/200500)
2. Proposal for merge of [column] into [columns] - [Jun 19](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136683/200500)
3. Merge of [column] into [columns] - [Jun 23](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/137367/200500)
4. Burnination of [column] - [Aug 4](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142256/200500)

I suspect when [column](/questions/tagged/column) was burninated it took [columns](/questions/tagged/columns) with it.

Answer (score 6):

Scenario: synonym from "A" to "B"; "B" does not actually exist

I'm not going to over-analyse the specific example; that could be rectified by any of:

- the following (see below)
- reversing the synonym
- merging the synonym (there are currently unmerged "column" questions)
- deleting the synonym

However, it seems odd that the tag "columns" doesn't exist when there's an approved synonym. My thinking is that the existing of an approved synonym effectively pre-validates the "columns" tag, so any code that is concerned about tag-creation should just assume "yep, that's OK". That is the fix I plan to apply.

Comment: Why do you have `the following` as the first list item?

Comment: @Asad because I think that is the best solution for anything except the immediate term